# Можно ли в Python записать в переменную то что вывел код

Tags: python

Какой нибудь код выполняется и записывает то он вывел в переменную. Можно ли такое реализовать в Python.
Вот пример:

```
cpu = psutil.cpu_times()
print(cpu)
```

То что выводит этот код записать в переменную или файл

Comment: Вас вероятно интересует перенаправление стандартного вывода: python app.py > file.txt

Comment: Использовать аргумент `file` в функции `print` или подменить `sys.stdout` на нужный вам файлоподобный объект (файл или StringIO)

Comment: Человек не понимает, что "то что выводит этот код" у него записано в переменной. А вы ему про перенаправление потоков.

Answer (score 0):

Да, просто пишешь:

имя_переменной = cpu

И все